# Uniform topology Autοmorphism group

Tags: operator-algebras

For $A$ a C* algebra the uniform topology in $Aut(A)$ is defined in terms of neighborhoods for every $a_1$ in $A$

$N(α_1,δ)=[α: ‖α_1∘α^{-1} ‖<δ]$

where

$‖α‖=[sup⁡{‖α(f)‖/‖f‖ ;f∈A,‖f‖≠0}].$

(Note: the square brackets should be curly)

Is this correct? Any bibliographical reference?

Comment: There's no $a_1$ in your definitions.

Comment: For any automorphism $\alpha\in Aut(A)$, we have $\|\alpha\|=1$ (in fact, $\alpha$ is an isometry).  Thus $N(\alpha_1,\delta)=\varnothing$ if $\delta\leq1$ and $=Aut(A)$ if $\delta>1$.  This doesn't seem to generate a useful topology on $Aut(A)$.